# add data to clipboard in OSX mac with objective-C using MIME

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, mime-types, clipboard

I am new to objective-C and Xcode. I want to know how can I add clipboard data using MIME type MDLCT Xcode for MAC applications. I have trouble doing this. I would appreciate if you help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: here is my code. I have developed an interface with two buttons that copies text to clipboard and show the clipboard content. I want to add the MDLCT format to the text. I want my program to show the clipboard content only if its format is MDLCT but when I click show content it show everything no matter what the format of the contents in clipboard is :